# How to get started with scribe in .Net?

Tags: .net, performance, logging, scalability

I had considered logging to a database cluster using log4net (we currently in the process of outgrowing the use of log4net to log to a single database), but [Scribe](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/scribeserver/index.php?title=Main_Page) looked like a [better](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=32008268919) [solution](http://highscalability.com/product-scribe-facebooks-scalable-logging-system), I've not had much success googling for alternatives, nor many examples of Scribe .net API's/Interfaces.

We have multiple application servers with millions of hits each per day and the Scribe architecture of push to a central repository and let that do the time consuming activities seems like a logical way forward.

Does anyone know where I can find good scribe examples for .Net, and are there any alternative scalable, distributed logging options I should be considering?

Comment: Is there a way I can improve my question, I'm asking how to get started with scribe, or any alternatives I should consider. I have updated my question, I hope that is to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help you with Scribe, so maybe my answer will be not helpful or even pointless.

I try to give our variant to

> and are there any alternative scalable, distributed logging options I
>   should be considering?

In our project we are using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) with similar goals. You don't give much details about required scalability so I can't decide is it suitable for you too.

NLog is compatible at source code level with log4net. I mean it requires small code changes to adapt your existing log4net logging code to log via NLog.

Take a look to supported [Targets](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Targets). You can use [Network Target](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Network_target) as is or write your own (it's pretty simple) to communicate with mentioned Scribe if you decided to use it.

You can use [Log2Console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/)'s source code as receiver example.

I can't give ready to use log server solution (except for commercials such as Gibraltar), but you can write your own as we done.

Personally I would not recommend to use direct database logging capabilities of any logging system (including log4net, NLog and etc.). Better provide additional level which will communicate with log providers (e.g. via network), aggregate data and do batch updates to database (log files) as it done in Scribe. It can increase overall performance of logging subsystem.

Comment: Did you know log for net can batch insert into the database... e.g. to write 100 at a time you can use  <bufferSize value="25" />, this is what we currently use and it can handle quite a lot!

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK log4net do batch insert by encapsulating them into single transaction. It gives performance boost over one by one insert of course, but you can achieve better performance in some cases (a lot of inserts) by using DBMS specific BULK INSERT operation. In case of MS SQL Server it can be done via SqlBulkCopy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

log4net chooses general solution since it provides ADO.NET wrapper. You can extend its default implementation by yourself with usage DBMS specific performance tweaks of course.

Comment: I made my suggestion since by using some middleware you can gather data at higher rates and do big single bulk insert comparing to solution where each logger do partial updates and stresses DBMS when number of loggers (and so number of connection to DBMS) grows up. It can be more efficient in case of you have a lot of logging data and / or loggers.